# In 1 Thessalonian 2:13 what does Paul mean by "logos"?

Tags: referent-identification, 1-thessalonians

> 1Th 2:13 KJV - 13 For this cause also thank we God without ceasing, because, when ye received **the word of God** which ye heard of us, ye received it not as **the word of men**, but as it is in truth, the **word of God**, which effectually worketh also in you that believe.
>
> 1Th 2:13 mGNT - 13  καὶ διὰ τοῦτο καὶ ἡμεῖς εὐχαριστοῦμεν τῷ θεῷ ἀδιαλείπτως ὅτι παραλαβόντες **λόγον** ἀκοῆς παρ᾽ ἡμῶν **τοῦ θεοῦ** ἐδέξασθε οὐ **λόγον ἀνθρώπων** ἀλλὰ καθώς ἐστιν ἀληθῶς **λόγον θεοῦ** ὃς καὶ ἐνεργεῖται ἐν ὑμῖν τοῖς πιστεύουσιν

How should "logos" be translated in each case and to what does it refer?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase ὁ λόγος τοῦ Θεοῦ (= the word of God) occurs in (slight) variations in 42 places such as Matt 15:6, Mark 7:13, Luke 5:1, 8:11, 21, 11:28, John 10:35, acts 4:31, 6:2, 7, 8:14, 11:1, 12:24, 13:5, 7, 46, 17:13, 18:11, Rom 9:6, 1 Cor 14:36, 2 Cor 2:17, Col 1:25, 1 Thess 2:13, 1 Tim 4:5, 2 Tim 2:9, Titus 2:5, Heb 4:12, 5:12, 13:7, 1 Peter 1:23, 2 Peter 3:5, 1 John 2:14, Rev 1:2, 9, 6:9, 17:17, 19:9, 13, 20:4.

A number of these discuss "hearing" the word of God (Luke 5:1, 8:21, 11:28, Acts 13:44, etc).  In Rev 1:2, John uses the term "ὁ λόγος τοῦ Θεοῦ" in a technical sense that can be deduced from the well-known "chain of Revelation"; here John appears to use the phrase to mean the testimony about Jesus which is "heard" (v3).

BDAG lists many of the above texts and simply observes:

> The apostles and other preachers with reference to the λόγος τοῦ Θεοῦ
>   are said to λαλεῖν Acts 4:29, 31, 13:46, Phil 1:14, Heb 13:7;
>   κατήγγελλον Acts 13:5, 17:13; διδάσκων Acts 18:11; μαρτυρίαν Rev 1:2. 
>   Of their hearers it is said: τὸν λόγον τοῦ Θεοῦ ἀκοῦσαι Acts 13:7;
>   δέδεκται Acts 8:14, 11:1.  Of the λόγος τοῦ Θεοῦ itself we read
>   ηὔξανεν Acts 6:7, 12:24, 19:20; οὐ δέδεται 2 Tim 2:9.  In these places
>   and many others ὁ λόγος τοῦ Θεοῦ is simply the Christian message, the
>   Gospel: Luke 5:1, 8:11, 21, 11:28. … Since the 'divine word' is
>   brought to humanity through Christ, his word can be used in the same
>   sense: τὸν λόγον μου John 5:24 …

Now specifically to 1 Thess 2:13.  The word "λόγος" occurs three times as follows:

- hearing the word of God from us
- you accepted not the word of men/humans
- but it is truly the word of God

The fact that what the apostles **preached** as the word of God and it was **heard** by the listeners, not as the word of humans but truly the word of God, suggests that "word of God" here is the spoken word, more specifically the Gospel message.  I also observe that the word of God has a work to do on the hearers - presumably transforming them (via the work of the Holy Spirit) into Christians worthy of the title.

Therefore, "λόγος" in 1 Thess 2:13 means the (spoken) Gospel message of the apostles.